# What to do when a question asker clearly hasn't googled?

Tags: discussion

What do you do when someone asks a question on a Stack Exchange site and that person clearly has not even attempted to google the answer? Downvote it? Something different?

Comment: Hate to ask, but .. did you umm.. search here prior to asking this?

Comment: @Some that's a terrible duplicate, though. The answers send the wrong message. (thanks for pointing that out, adding an answer there...)

Comment: @probablyPekka I guess but do we really need another question where someone comes to meta complaining about lack of research?

Comment: @Some no, dupe-closing is perfectly fine, you're right

Comment: @TimPost Yes, I did.  I don't think that the proposed "already answered" question answers my question.

Comment: @CDub Fair enough :) I just wanted to make sure you were aware of it (had not seen the close vote prior to adding my comment)

Comment: @CDub then how can you accept and appreciate the exact duplicate answer that is on the other question as well.

Comment: Because I believe both questions were answered at nearly the same time by the same author.  And besides that, it answers my question and should get credit for doing so.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What I do when a question is so trivial that it can *easily* be googled:

- Downvote
- Closevote, often as "Off-Topic" -> "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a **minimal understanding** of the problem being solved."
- If it's a newbie, leave a comment along the lines of "Hi, please always remember to Google first. A simple query for `how to flobber the gargle`  should give you everything you need."

Comment: This is plajarism from your [other answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/204014/186285)!!!

Comment: @Cole but I asked the author. He's cool with it.

Comment: Please stop flagging this as plagiarism. For goodness sake, this guy sells knock-off Gucci handbags as a hobby, and all you people are worried about is a little copied paragraph?